# form:input path giving exception

Tags: java, spring, jsp

hi in my jsp i am writing the input text field with spring tag like below

```
<div class="frmpnlbrdr">
                <%-- <input type="hidden" name="<csrf:token-name/>"     value="<csrf:token-value uri="modelGPStatus.htm"/>" />
                <input type="hidden" id="formName" name="formName" /> --%>
                <form:label path="localGovCode"><center><h2>Enter Local Government Code</h2></center>
            <form:input path="localGovCode"  id="localGovCode" name="localGovCode" size="20" style="height:25px" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"/></form:label>
            </div>
```

it is throwing the exception like below

> javax.servlet.ServletException: File
>   "/WEB-INF/views/component/demand/awareness/error.jsp" not
>   found     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.handleMissingResource(JspServlet.java:412)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:593)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:530)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:652)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:869)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:840)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.component.demand.awareness.modelGPStatus_jsp._jspService(modelGPStatus_jsp.java:977)
>     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:574)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   in.nic.pes.common.interceptor.AUthenticatUserFilter.doFilter(AUthenticatUserFilter.java:23)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at com.org.ep.help.HelpFilter.doFilter(HelpFilter.java:74)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   com.org.ep.interceptor.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:37)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)

so can any one please tell me what mistake i am doing and how to write the tag

Comment: You mean to say that you want to display the error.jsp ? The code snippet, unless you have compilation errors, can't identify anything. What's causing the error and which line causes it?

Comment: <form:input path="localGovCode"  id="localGovCode" name="localGovCode" size="20" style="height:25px" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"/> this line is giving exception i don't want to display any error page

Comment: Please add your JSP and your Controller code. The only mistake in here code would be the `path="localGovCode"` .

Comment: this is my controller method                                                                                             @RequestMapping(value = "modelGPStatus.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String GpStatusSubmit(HttpServletRequest request, Map<String, Object> model, HttpSession session, @ModelAttribute("modelGPStatusEntity") ModelGPStatusEntity modelGPStatusEntity) {

Comment: and my  jsp    <form:form  method="post" action="modelGPStatus.htm" commandName="modelGPStatusEntity" name="modelGPStatusEntity" id="modelGPStatusEntity">

Comment: Please add all these info as part of question..the controller code etc